# @selector - How to call a method from another class?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I had created an NSMenu via Interface Builder. One of the menu items called showPreferencesPanel method, which is defined in KBAppController.m:

```
-(void)showPreferencesPanel {
    //something
}
```

Now, I have to re-build the menu without IB...all programmatically. StatusMenu.m is the class that deals with all that, and I can't figure out the target that I should set so that a method is called from another class.

Creating an instance of that class didn't work! The menu item is grayed out.

**StatusMenu.m**

```
KBAppController *kbAppController = [[KBAppController alloc]init];
NSMenuItem* preferencesItem;
[preferencesItem setTarget:kbAppController];
preferencesItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Preferences…" action:@selector(showPreferencesPanel) keyEquivalent:@""];
```

**Edited:-------------------------------------------**

Here is the updated code that uses an object of class KBAppController. The good news is that the prefs menu item is enabled, but it still doesn't call the method in KBAppController.m :(

**KBStatusMenu.m**

```
@synthesize kbAppController = _kbAppController;

someMethod {   
NSMenuItem* preferencesItem;
preferencesItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Preferences…" action:@selector(showPreferencesPanel) keyEquivalent:@""];
[preferencesItem setTarget:self];
}

- (void)showPreferencesPanel {
NSLog(@"in 1");
[_kbAppController showPreferencesPanel];
}
```

**KBAppController.m**

```
-(void)showPreferencesPanel {
    NSLog(@"in 2");
    //something
}
```

Comment: Does this print out anything?

Comment: yes, it got to "in 1", but never to "in 2". _kbAppController was empty! I removed the property and @synthesize statements, and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the `selector` call the method from your class. And inside that method, call `showPreferencePanel()` with the object of `KBAPPController` .

Make sure to set the object of KBAppController as a property of StatusMenu.

Comment: thanks, I edit my question to include the new code. It still doesn't call the method from another class. where am I messing up?

Comment: set a break point in `showPreferencesPanel` and find out if `_kbAppController` is not nil

Comment: ok, I created an instance of KBAppController, and I didn't set it as property. I removed the @synthesize, and it's working now. I am confused as to why it didn't work as property though.

Comment: Wait. why didnt you add it as a property ?

Comment: I defined an instance in KBStatisMenu.h: `KBAppController *kbAppController`, and removed @property (and @synthesize). For some reason, when I keep these statements my kbAppController object in .m file end up `nil`, and so it doesn't call anything!

Comment: Oh! I wasn't declaring my property correctly, I was using `assign' instead of `@property (retain) IBOutlet KBAppController *kbAppController`. (sorry I am new to this)

Comment: I see. Use nonatomic, and strong.

Answer (score 1):

NSMenuItem has a `- (void)setTarget:(id)anObject` and `- (void)setAction:(SEL)aSelector` that should do that trick.

Just make sure you set up and init the NSMenuItem first.  Right now you are calling `-setAction` on an uninitialized object.

```
preferencesItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Preferences…" action:@selector(showPreferencesPanel) keyEquivalent:@""];
[preferencesItem setTarget:kbAppController]
```